# Variable conflict using JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

I have problem with variables in javascript. My situation is:

In PHP file i have:

```
<div class="fd_text" onmouseover="zobraz_text('pom','1','1')" onmouseout="zobraz_text('pom','1','0')">something in</div>
```

In JS file I have:

```
var pom1 = "Some text1";
var pom2 = "Some text2";

function zobraz_text(firma, cislo, udalost){
    obsah_text = firma+cislo; //this is wrong and why I wrote lower in text under this code

    document.getElementById("bloks").innerHTML = document.getElementById("bloks").innerHTML + obsah_text; //this ID is correct
}
```

`obsah_text` is variable which must add texts from `pom1`, `pom2`, etc...
Where `pom1` and where `pom2` I get from `mouseover` which is in PHP file.

If I group first two parametrs from function `zobraz_text` I gave `pom1`, but this `pom1` isn´t same as `pom1` where I have text. On web I have text `"pom1"`, but I must have text `"Some text1"`.

My code works when I delete variable `obsah_text` and simply add variable `pom1` as in this example code.

This show me text from variable and this is ok but if I add variable then this code works only in 1 of 300 situation (for that I have first and second parametrs in function `zobraz_text()` )

```
document.getElementById("bloks").innerHTML = document.getElementById("bloks").innerHTML + pom1;
```

I believe that you understand and help me. I expect it will be for many of you simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't create variables of variables.  If `pom1` and `pom2` were global, you could potentially do `window[firma + cislo]`, but I wouldn't recommend that.

Instead, use an object to store the poms:

```
var poms = {
    "pom1": "Some text1",
    "pom2": "Some text2",
}
//snip
obsah_text = poms[firma + cislo];
```